# Help me find this Fantasy book about a girl and her female mentor

Tags: story-identification, books

So I read this book on Wattpad, but I remember it also being a published book. 
I remember it being about a girl who is a huntress in training and lives with other huntresses.

It's custom for the women to train at a young age in this guild of sorts, her mother did the same thing before her. Later on a strange woman appears and the MC heals her from her wounds But everyone isn't sure whether they should trust this new stranger or not. The MC starts looking up to her as a fellow mentor, (Each of these trainees have a mentor, one of them is abusive to the MC's friend) but they don't know if the new stranger should be fully trusted. There are some LGBT themes as well.

Comment: Took me a minute to guess that MC == main character